# Is there a way to use the clearfix hack alongside flexbox?

Tags: css, css-float, flexbox, clearfix

I've been using flexbox for layouts, with CSS floats as a fallback for older browsers. On the whole this works well, since browsers that understand `display: flex` will ignore float on any flex items.

However, the one place that I've run into a problem with this approach is with clearfix. [Clearfix](http://cssmojo.com/latest_new_clearfix_so_far/) is a widely-used hack that uses an invisible `:after` pseudo-element to make a container properly clear / contain any floated elements inside it. However, the problem is that this pseudo-element is treated as a flex item by browsers that support flexbox, which can lead to unexpected layout issues. For example, if you have two flex items and use `justify-content: space-between`, instead of being positioned at the start and end of the flex container, they will appear in the start and middle, with the invisible clearfix `::after` pseudo-element taking the end position.

My question is: is there a way to use clearfix alongside a flexbox layout without causing these problems?

Comment: You might use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download) to detect flexbox support and hide that `::after` element.

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this would be to consider alternative clearfix methods.

The `::after` pseudo-element is one method but, as you noted, it becomes a flex item in a flex container. ([See Box #81 in this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)).

But there are various other ways to clear floats. For instance, you could use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`.

Check out some alternatives here:

- [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)
- [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/3597276)
- [Clearing Floats: An Overview of Different clearfix Methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

---

Another way to solve your problem uses [**modernizr.com**](https://modernizr.com/) for feature detection.

*From the website:*

> All web developers come up against differences between browsers and
>   devices. That’s largely due to different feature sets: the latest
>   versions of the popular browsers can do some awesome things which
>   older browsers can’t – but we still have to support the older ones.
>
> Modernizr makes it easy to deliver tiered experiences: make use of the
>   latest and greatest features in browsers which support them, without
>   leaving less fortunate users high and dry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will deal with pseudo-elements in a flex container:

```
.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  flex-basis: 0;
  order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue you were having, but I was using a fairly complicated flex setup:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
align-items: center;
```

I ran into a similar issue where I wanted to use clearfix to make sure I could split the content at a certain point, in my case it was to make some data break on specific screen sizes. I was absoutely stumped until I found a solution through trial and error that worked for me:

```
<div class="clearflex"></div>

.clearflex{
    width:100%;
}
```

By adding an empty div with 100% width between flex content it seems to make that content break onto the new line exactly like clearfix did. You can also added a height to clearflex if you need some padding between the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can set flex-wrap to your flex container and width: 100% to after pseudo element so it will wrap and not mess with alignment.

Comment: I've just tried this and it doesn't seem to work, as far as I can tell. The `:after` pseudo-element just takes up all the remaining space but doesn't wrap (so it's as if you are using `justify-content: flex-start`). Can you point me to a working example of this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` on `.clearfix` & completely remove `.clearfix::after`.

```
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;  /* or overflow: hidden; */
}
```

However, if you can't use `overflow` property on `.clearfix` for some reason, you can use `margin-left: auto` on the second div (considering your layout has only two column). That way the invisible `::after` will be placed in between two layout divs.

```
.clearfix { ... }
.clearfix::after { .... }
.clearfix > div:last-of-type {
    margin-left: auto;
    /* for justify-content: space-between only.
    * For other option, adjust accordingly */
}
```